# Error Code "1375" meaning in Inetlab SMPP Library

Tags: .net, smpp, bulksms, inetlab.smpp

I implemented a code to send bulk SMS using dotnet Inetlab.SMPP library. I send large number of messages (700K) for example. it works well and send most of the messages successfully. but in some of them it return error code (1375) [I attached screenshot of response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/21GM9.png). I searched a lot to figure out the meaning of this code but could not find. please help.
Attached below part of code: the error occurs on {submitResponses[0].Header):

```
List<string> numbers = transactions.Select(x => x.MSISDN).ToList();

                    var bulkList = SMS.ForSubmitMulti()
                        .From(_config[$"Smpp:{sender}"])
                        .Coding(DataCodings.UCS2)
                        .Text(msg.SmsContent);

                    foreach (var transaction in transactions)
                    {
                        bulkList
                        .To(transaction.MSISDN);
                    }

                    bulkList.Create(_client);

                    var submitResponses = await _client.SubmitAsync(bulkList);

                    if (submitResponses.Any(x => x.Header.Status == CommandStatus.ESME_ROK || (int)x.Header.Status == Static_SMS_Success))
                    {
                        success++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        fail++;
                        Log.ForContext("Type", "SMSResponses").Error($"Content: Fail at {submitResponses[0]}, Response: {submitResponses[0].Header.ToString()}, MessageId: {submitResponses[0].MessageId}");
                    }

                    await _client.DisconnectAsync();
```

I try to send large number of bulk SMS excepting them to be send successfully.

Answer (score 0):

The command_status in range 0x00000500-0xFFFFFFFF is reserved for any purpose.
Please ask SMPP provider or mobile network operator you are connecting to, what the status 1375 means in their system.

See SMPP v.3.4 section 5.1.3.